# UITableview reloading tableview and cell

Tags: uitableview, swift2

I am trying to reload my table view using

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

It works properly if I'm loading static datasource using array. Everything work properly. 
But when I try to use my query function with parse, it loads a new cell but the contents of the tableview cell doesn't change. If I re-open the app, the cells will update properly.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "EmpPostTVCellIdentifier"
    let cell: EmpPostTVCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as? EmpPostTVCell

    //If datasource

    if dataSource.isEmpty{
        fetchDataFromParse()
        print("no posts")
    }

        let itemArr:PFObject = self.dataSource[indexPath.row]
        cell?.companyPostLabel.text = (PFUser.currentUser()?.objectForKey("companyName")!.capitalizedString)! as String
        cell?.occupationPostLabel.text = itemArr["occupation"]!.capitalizedString as String
        cell?.countryPostLabel.text = itemArr["country"]!.capitalizedString as String
        let companyImage: PFFile?
        companyImage = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectForKey("profileImageEmployer") as? PFFile
        companyImage?.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (data, error) -> Void in
            if error == nil{
                cell?.companyLogoImage.image = UIImage(data: data!)
            }
        })

        let dateArr = createdByDate[indexPath.row]
        let strDate = Settings.dateFormatter(dateArr)

        cell?.closingDateLabel .text = strDate



    return cell!
}
```

I am using pull to refresh my tableviews contents using this code

```
func refresh(sender:AnyObject)
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        self.fetchDataFromParse()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
    })

}
```

with or without the dispatch_asynch function the results remains the same. It just add new tableviewcell but the contents in it does not change. Any ideas guys?

edit 1 :

```
func fetchDataFromParse() {
    //        MARK: - JOB POST QUERY
    if PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId == nil{
        PFUser.currentUser()?.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success, error) -> Void in
            let query = PFQuery(className: "JobPost")
            //creating a pointer
            let userPointer = PFUser.objectWithoutDataWithObjectId(PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId)

            query.whereKey("postedBy", equalTo: userPointer)

            query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
            let objects = query.findObjects()
            for object in (objects as? [PFObject])!{
                //print(object.objectId)
                self.dataSource.append(object)
                self.createdByDate.append((object.objectForKey("closingDate") as? NSDate)!)
                print(self.dataSource)
                print(self.createdByDate)
            }
        })
    } else {
        let query = PFQuery(className: "JobPost")
        //creating a pointer
        let userPointer = PFUser.objectWithoutDataWithObjectId(PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId)

        query.whereKey("postedBy", equalTo: userPointer)

        query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
        let objects = query.findObjects()
        for object in (objects as? [PFObject])!{
            //print(object.objectId)
            self.dataSource.append(object)
            self.createdByDate.append((object.objectForKey("closingDate") as? NSDate)!)
            print(self.dataSource)
            print(self.createdByDate)

        }
    }//end of PFUser objectID == nil else clause
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see the content of the fetchDataFromParse() function where I presume you're filling the self.dataSource array

Comment: try this instead of tableview.reloadData() - 
self.tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: 0), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)

Comment: You should try putting self.tableView.reloadData() and
        self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing() inside fetchDataFromParse() after the for loop that appends to the datasource array, that way it will only reload after the data has been appended.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call self.tableview.reloadData() when fetchDataFromParse() is finished.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your dataSource array is empty at the end of your fetchDataFromParse method

Comment: I guess that's not it, because when I re-open the app, the tableviewcells are updated and fine.

Answer (score 0):

PFUser.currentUser()?.saveInBackgroundWithBlock is an asynchronus method. So your tableView cell is having no data.

Comment: any sample solution would do :/

Comment: plus this line only runs if the user is nil, to avoid error "unsaved object". You should stop pointing out without supporting your answer.